# Prometheus Installation by helm gives timeout exceeded

Tags: timeout, kubernetes-helm

When I install helm chart of prometheus it gives this error

"W0729 22:11:30.483798   18647 transport.go:260] Unable to cancel request for *exec.roundTripper
E0729 22:11:30.484005   18647 request.go:1027] Unexpected error when reading response body: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout or context cancellation while reading body)
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unexpected error when reading response body. Please retry. Original error: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout or context cancellation while reading body)"